# VSCode C/C++ extension highlights C++ errors when only writing C

Tags: c, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to use the VSCode C/C++ extension to write C, and it is sugggesting that I have errors which are only relevant to C++ such as

```
a value of type "void *" cannot be used to initialize an entity of type "input_t"
```

when trying to `malloc`. Is there a way I can disable C++ suggestions, I don't see this in the settings. It's detecting C as the language and not C++.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with this extension but also many more.
This is why I now use the **clangd** extension (which is also faster to detect errors & warnings).

Just create a file named **compile_flags.txt** at the project's root containing `-I ./{path_to_.h_files}`.

Used with **B Ear** for clang tools, `bear --make re` and it works perfectly (be careful not to have two compile_flags.txt)

Comment: the problem is because of wrong configs. You need to specify C in the json file

Comment: Can you elaborate on how to specify this?

Comment: Bear is a tool that generates a compilation database for clang tooling.
After installation the usage is like this:
bear -- <your-build-command>